# How I convert special characters fetched from tt_content.bodytext column in typo3 backend editor?

Tags: internationalization, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, htmlspecialchars

Typo3 stores webpage content in **tt_content** table having charset **utf-8**. In mycase it is stored in **hungarian** language. In **tt_content.bodytext** column special characters are stored.Hence same **untranslated** characters are being rendered in webpage.

**Ex**: Ã³ to be converted to é

I have tried with changing **setLocale** to **utf-8** in **Localconfiguration.php** file. But not getting the result. ried various solutions from google but no success.

I am really new to typo3 6.2. . Please guide me step by step to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UTF-8 is a character encoding, not a Locale, so the change won't be helpful.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I agree. It was a typo.. I also tried most of character encoding steps in typo3 end but couldn't fix it. Can you please let me know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 6.0 all data from and to database must be utf-8 on all levels.
Have a view into your database to see whether your text fields, your database and your database connection is utf-8.

Make sure all transfer to and from database outside from TYPO3 is done with utf-8.

These wrong character encodings often were problems when the encodings does not match.
since 6.0 TYPO3 always uses utf-8 database connection although the data fields can be Iso-something declared. Aside from the missing space for two or three byte utf-8 characters, you get trash characters if interfering with the database with other software which uses only the declared encoding.